# Why is List<String> accepting another <List> as an element

Tags: java, generics

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class Hello {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{

        String[] veri2 = {"No", "Compilation", "Error"};

        List<String> veri1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        veri1.addAll(Arrays.asList(veri2)); // ---------- 14
        System.out.println(veri1+"elements in hashset");

    } 

}
```

Why the above code doesnt throw a compile error at line  14  when a List is added to another List whose elemnts are of type String ?

Comment: `addAll` takes a `Collection`, and `Arrays.asList` returns a `List<T>`, with `T` being `String` in your case...so what's the problem?

Comment: veri2 is also an array of string being converted to a list of string. It seems very valid to me

Comment: @Richards: We're adding List<String> to a List<String>..

Comment: @Nick, yea just realized that..

Comment: My question was that -- to a list which accepts only string objects we are addin a list(Arrays.asList) leaving aside what this List contains which is immaterial

Comment: yaa got it .. ...List.addAll takes a collection.By this method we can overcome the Generic Type Safety ... littl aaawh kind of thng ..

Comment: Now I am clear ..Gyz Thanx ... compile time safety is still ensured .. crosschckd with List of inetegrs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`List<E>.addAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method accepts a `Collection<? extends E>`, and the `List<E>` interface inherits from `Collection<E>`.

If you *tried* to add a `String` using `addAll`, you would actually get an error.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll("Hello");
```

The above code wouldn't work, since `String` does not implement `Collection<String>`.

Comment: @whataheck: No, generics are working properly to enforce compile-time correctness. You're adding all the `String`s from one `List<String>` to another. You couldn't do `stringList.addAll(integerList)`.

Comment: @Colin Excellent tHnx .. when I add a List of Integers thru addAll ,it throws a compile time error ......

Answer (score 3):

The signature in your case is `addAll(Collection<String> c)` and since you pass a `List<String>` which extends `Collection<String>` all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` is generic and since your array is an array of `String`, it returns a `List<String>`, which is exactly what you want.

see: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect a compiler error? The signature of `addAll()` is:

```
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

So in your case:

```
boolean addAll(Collection<? extends String> c)
```

And Arrays.asList():

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

Which means for your

```
public static List<String> asList(String... a)
```

So `addAll()` wants a `Collection<? extends String>` and gets a `List<String>` - which is perfectly OK.

Comment: yaa got it .. .To ask u a dffrnt one .. I culdnt get what this means ,,,, many times .. boolean addAll(Collection [-- <? extends E>  --] c)
the one in [-- -]                                                     Collection<? extends String> does this mean the collection contains objects sof String . What does extends signify

Comment: @whataheck: It's a bounded wildcard ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html ) - it means a Collection that contains only instaces of some unknown class which is String or a subclass thereof

Answer (score 1):

Because Arrays.asList() returns a List.  In your case it is interpreting your String[] and setting that as the type.

Answer (score 0):

When you add all the elements of a List<String> to a List<String> this is the one occasion you shouldn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because addAll adds each element of a collection to a list.  If you had called add, you presumably would have gotten the error you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [List API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
public boolean addAll(Collection c)
```

Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list...

So no type error because addAll receives Collection (List is a Collection) as argument and adds them to the list.